# Different price for product added to cart as simple product or as part of a bundle product?

Tags: product, price, bundled-product, bundle

let’s say I have a simple product named “Pentium i7” with the price §300 that can be added to the cart as a simple product. Also, the “Pentium i7” product can be chosen as an option for a bundle product.

Is it possible to use a different price when added to the cart as part of a bundle product than being added to the cart as a simple product?

What I already did is to create a custom module overriding the price_model for bundled products:

```
<config>
...
<global>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <bundle translate="label" module="catalog">
                    <price_model>**_Functions_Bundle_Model_Product_Price</price_model>
                </bundle>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
</global>
</config>
```

Am I on the right track? Any help would be appreciated!

Oliver

Comment: Anyone? What I basically want is to set a bundle product's price type to fixed before adding it to the cart even though the actual bundle product's price type is set to dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

This is built-in with bundles. When setting up a new product you can set custom pricing for simple products in a bundle option / selection - to do so you have to set pricing to be 'fixed' instead of 'dynamic'.

[image: bundle custom pricing]

Comment: Hey philwinkle, thanks! The problem is that the bundle products need to have dynamic pricing. Under certain conditions, however, I need to switch prices of products that are being part of a bundle products.

Comment: Sometimes with Magento you have to do some hard work - that may mean setting custom pricing for each bundle. I'm sorry to say that what you're asking is not really possible as-is. 

Can you give me some kind of direction what the *special conditions* you mention might be?

Comment: Well, basically our bundle has 3 options. You need to choose at least one. If the second option is chosen, I need to use different prices for the 1st and 2nd chosen selection. If only the first option is chosen, the base price of the simple product will be used. I'm having hard times to determine which options are selected after the bundle has been added to the cart.